# How do you change the color of the dotted line on Google map v3 directions

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on Transit directions and have been able to change the color of polyline displayed for transit route using polylineOptions property.

However, I am not able to change the color of dotted line displayed for walking directions.

I did come across this solution, but it doesnt work for v3 (tried with v3.22)

[Similar StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938641/how-do-you-change-the-color-of-the-dotted-line-on-returned-google-map-directions)

I have included a working example in this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hxj4j8bs/)

```js
var directions = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var renderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
  polylineOptions: {
    strokeColor: '#C83939',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 7
  }

});
var map, transitLayer;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7482333, -73.8681295),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('go'), 'click',
    route);

  var input = document.getElementById('from');
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  transitLayer = new google.maps.TransitLayer();

  var control = document.getElementById('transit-wpr');
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(control);

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(control, 'click', function() {
    transitLayer.setMap(transitLayer.getMap() ? null : map);
  });

  addDepart();
  route();
}

function addDepart() {
  var depart = document.getElementById('depart');
  for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 60; j += 15) {
      var x = i < 10 ? '0' + i : i;
      var y = j < 10 ? '0' + j : j;
      depart.innerHTML += '<option>' + x + ':' + y + '</option>';
    }
  }
}

function route() {
  var departure = document.getElementById('depart').value;
  var bits = departure.split(':');
  var now = new Date();
  var tzOffset = (now.getTimezoneOffset() + 60) * 60 * 1000;

  var time = new Date();
  time.setHours(bits[0]);
  time.setMinutes(bits[1]);

  var ms = time.getTime() - tzOffset;
  if (ms < now.getTime()) {
    ms += 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  }

  var departureTime = new Date(ms);

  var request = {
    origin: document.getElementById('from').value,
    destination: '51 St, New York, NY 10022, USA',
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT,
    provideRouteAlternatives: true,
    transitOptions: {
      departureTime: departureTime
    }
  };

  var panel = document.getElementById('panel');
  panel.innerHTML = '';
  directions.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      renderer.setDirections(response);
      renderer.setMap(map);
      renderer.setPanel(panel);
      console.log(renderer.getDirections());
    } else {
      renderer.setMap(null);
      renderer.setPanel(null);
    }

  });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: black;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}
#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
}
#panel-wpr {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
#panel {
  font-family: arial;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
#info {
  padding: 5px;
}
#from {
  width: 90%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.adp-directions {
  width: 100%;
}
.input {
  background-color: white;
  padding-left: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
  border-top: 1px solid silver;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;
}
.time {
  margin: 0;
  height: 17px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-top-color: #CCC;
  border-right-color: #999;
  border-left-color: #999;
  border-bottom-color: #CCC;
  padding: 2px 15px 1px 1px;
}
button {
  border: 1px solid #3079ED;
  color: white;
  background-color: #4D90FE;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#4D90FE), to(#4787ED));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE, #4787ED);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE, #4787ED);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE, #4787ED);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE, #4787ED);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE, #4787ED);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#4d90fe', EndColorStr='#4787ed');
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 54px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 8px;
  line-height: 27px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.218s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.218s;
  -o-transition: all 0.218s;
  transition: all 0.218s;
}
#info div {
  line-height: 22px;
  font-size: 110%;
}
.btn {} #panel-wpr {
  border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}
#info {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Transit</title>
<div id="transit-wpr">
  <button id="transit">Toggle transit layer</button>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="panel-wpr">
  <div id="info">
    <div>
      <h2>Transit directions</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>from:</label>
      <input class="input" id="from" value="Grand Central 42, NY">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>to:</label>
      <strong>51 St, New York, NY 10022, USA</strong>
    </div>
    <div>Depart at
      <select id="depart"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
      <button id="go">Get Directions</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="panel"></div>
</div>
```

Any property available which I have missed, or this is not possible?

Comment: I did try using icons property of polylineOptions, but that doesnt work either. polylineOptions: {
                    strokeColor: '#C83939',
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                    strokeWeight: 7,
                    icons: [{
                        icon: {
                            fillColor: '#C83939', //or hexadecimal color such as: '#FF0000'
                            strokeColor: '#C83939'
                        
                        }
                    }]
                }

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue **in the question itself**.

Comment: Hi, I have included a JS Fiddle in the Question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The options for these lines are fixed and will not be affected by the polylineOptions of the DirectionsRenderer.

The polylineOptions for these dotted lines will (currently) be set by the API to:

```
{
  "icons": [{
    "icon": {
      "path": 0,
      "scale": 3,
      "fillOpacity": 0.7,
      "fillColor": "#00b3fd",
      "strokeOpacity": 0.8,
      "strokeColor": "#3379c3",
      "strokeWeight": 1
    },
    "repeat": "10px"
  }],
  "strokeColor": "#000000",
  "strokeOpacity": 0,
  "strokeWeight": 5
}
```

...any custom polylineOption of the DirectionsRenderer will be ignored.

A possible workaround(but it will only be possible to set a single fixed value for all these dotted lines):

```js
function initMap() {
     var  goo = google.maps,
          map = new goo.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                  zoom: 7,
                  center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}
                }),
          directionsService       = new goo.DirectionsService,
          directionsDisplay       = new goo.DirectionsRenderer({
                                      map:map,
                                      polylineOptions:{
                                        strokeColor:'red'
                                      }});
      google.maps.Polyline.prototype.setMap=(function(f,r){
      
        return function(map){
          if(
            this.get('icons')
              &&
            this.get('icons').length===1
              &&
            this.get('strokeOpacity')===0
              &&
            !this.get('noRoute')
          ){
            if(r.get('polylineOptions')&& r.get('polylineOptions').strokeColor){
              
              var icons=this.get('icons'),
                  color=r.get('polylineOptions').strokeColor;
              icons[0].icon.fillOpacity=1;
              icons[0].icon.fillColor=color;
              icons[0].icon.strokeColor=color;
              this.set('icons',icons);
          }}
        f.apply(this,arguments);
      }
      
     })(
          google.maps.Polyline.prototype.setMap,
          directionsDisplay);
    
  
  directionsService.route({
    origin: new google.maps.LatLng(52.549917, 13.42539669),
    destination: new google.maps.LatLng(52.541843, 13.4206566),
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html, body,#map  {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
```

It overrides the `setMap`-method of `google.maps.Polyline`

It checks if

1. the strokeOpacity is 0
2. a IconSequence with a single icon is present
3. it doesn't have a `noRoute`-property(in the case that you draw polylines on your own which match the first 2 condition set a `noRoute`-option to true, otherwise they will be affected too)

When all 3 conditions are true, it will modify the icons-property of the polyline.

Answer (score 1):

There is no property (currently) that allows that part of the polyline to be styled.  One option is to hide the DirectionRenderer Polyline and render the polylines yourself, that gives you complete control over the separate polylines.

```
var polylineOptions = {
  strokeColor: '#C83939',
  strokeOpacity: 1,
  strokeWeight: 4
};
var walkingPolylineOptions = {
  strokeColor: '#C83939',
  strokeOpacity: 0,
  strokeWeight: 4,
  icons: [{
    icon: {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      fillColor: '#C83939',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      scale: 2,
      strokeColor: '#C83939',
      strokeOpacity: 1,
    },
    offset: '0',
    repeat: '10px'
  }]
};

function renderDirectionsPolylines(response) {
  var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
  for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
    var steps = legs[i].steps;
    for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
      var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
      var stepPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline(polylineOptions);
      if (steps[j].travel_mode == google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING) {
        stepPolyline.setOptions(walkingPolylineOptions)
      }
      for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
        stepPolyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
      }
      stepPolyline.setMap(map);
    }
  }
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/hxj4j8bs/8/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var polylineOptions = {
  strokeColor: '#C83939',
  strokeOpacity: 1,
  strokeWeight: 4
};
var walkingPolylineOptions = {
  strokeColor: '#C83939',
  strokeOpacity: 0,
  strokeWeight: 4,
  icons: [{
    icon: {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      fillColor: '#C83939',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      scale: 2,
      strokeColor: '#C83939',
      strokeOpacity: 1,
    },
    offset: '0',
    repeat: '10px'
  }]
};

function renderDirectionsPolylines(response) {
  var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
  for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
    var steps = legs[i].steps;
    for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
      var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
      var stepPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline(polylineOptions);
      if (steps[j].travel_mode == google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING) {
        stepPolyline.setOptions(walkingPolylineOptions)
      }
      for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
        stepPolyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
      }
      stepPolyline.setMap(map);
    }
  }
}

var directions = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var renderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
  suppressPolylines: true,
});
var map, transitLayer;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7482333, -73.8681295),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('go'), 'click',
    route);

  var input = document.getElementById('from');
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  transitLayer = new google.maps.TransitLayer();

  var control = document.getElementById('transit-wpr');
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(control);

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(control, 'click', function() {
    transitLayer.setMap(transitLayer.getMap() ? null : map);
  });

  addDepart();
  route();
}

function addDepart() {
  var depart = document.getElementById('depart');
  for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 60; j += 15) {
      var x = i < 10 ? '0' + i : i;
      var y = j < 10 ? '0' + j : j;
      depart.innerHTML += '<option>' + x + ':' + y + '</option>';
    }
  }
}

function route() {
  var departure = document.getElementById('depart').value;
  var bits = departure.split(':');
  var now = new Date();
  var tzOffset = (now.getTimezoneOffset() + 60) * 60 * 1000;
  var time = new Date();
  time.setHours(bits[0]);
  time.setMinutes(bits[1]);
  var ms = time.getTime() - tzOffset;
  if (ms < now.getTime()) {
    ms += 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  }
  var departureTime = new Date(ms);
  var request = {
    origin: document.getElementById('from').value,
    destination: '51 St, New York, NY 10022, USA',
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT,
    provideRouteAlternatives: true,
    transitOptions: {
      departureTime: departureTime
    }
  };
  var panel = document.getElementById('panel');
  panel.innerHTML = '';
  directions.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      renderer.setDirections(response);
      renderer.setMap(map);
      renderer.setPanel(panel);
      renderDirectionsPolylines(response);
      console.log(renderer.getDirections());
    } else {
      renderer.setMap(null);
      renderer.setPanel(null);
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: black;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}
#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
}
#panel-wpr {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
#panel {
  font-family: arial;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
#info {
  padding: 5px;
}
#from {
  width: 90%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.adp-directions {
  width: 100%;
}
.input {
  background-color: white;
  padding-left: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
  border-top: 1px solid silver;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;
}
.time {
  margin: 0;
  height: 17px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-top-color: #CCC;
  border-right-color: #999;
  border-left-color: #999;
  border-bottom-color: #CCC;
  padding: 2px 15px 1px 1px;
}
button {
  border: 1px solid #3079ED;
  color: white;
  background-color: #4D90FE;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#4D90FE), to(#4787ED));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE, #4787ED);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE, #4787ED);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE, #4787ED);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE, #4787ED);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE, #4787ED);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#4d90fe', EndColorStr='#4787ed');
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 54px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 8px;
  line-height: 27px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.218s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.218s;
  -o-transition: all 0.218s;
  transition: all 0.218s;
}
#info div {
  line-height: 22px;
  font-size: 110%;
}
.btn {} #panel-wpr {
  border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}
#info {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.22&libraries=places&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Transit</title>
<div id="transit-wpr">
  <button id="transit">Toggle transit layer</button>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="panel-wpr">
  <div id="info">
    <div>
      <h2>Transit directions</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>from:</label>
      <input class="input" id="from" value="Grand Central 42, NY" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>to:</label>
      <strong>51 St, New York, NY 10022, USA</strong>
    </div>
    <div>Depart at
      <select id="depart"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
      <button id="go">Get Directions</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="panel"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: the error is raised in this example, http://jsfiddle.net/8xw377u5/ where I have set source to LaGuardia Airport. UnCaught error is raised in the console.

Comment: I have tried this for several examples, usually error is raised for longer routes. Also tried both methods, getPanel + pushing coordinates and setPanel method. Issue persists in both.

Comment: Looks like there is an issue deep in the Google Maps Javascript API adding icons to the polylines for the walking directions when suppressPolylines is true (at least that is my suspicion, this is the line that generates the error: `FX(this,q,LX).set("icons",[MX])`). If I [don't add the renderer to the map](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/8xw377u5/4/), I don't see that error.

Comment: have logged in API issue tracker - https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9339