# Getting rid of station markers with Google Directions API transit mode

Tags: google-maps-api-3, markers, directions

Google Directions API adds station markers when the mode is set to transit like the 5R marker in this example:

[image: transit mode directions]

The suppressMarkers option suppresses the A and B markers, but does not suppress the station marker.  What can we do to get rid of the station marker?

Comment: Are the "station markers" you are referring to the "white dots"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure potter was talking about the 5R marker above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll see those station markers if you render the route using the DirectionsRenderer. I'm not sure if there's any way to suppress them with that approach. However there is another option for rendering the route which won't display them in the first place, which is to render a polyline using the path from the directions api response, e.g.

```
new google.maps.Polyline({"path": response.routes[0].overview_path, ...})
```

Answer (score 3):

related question: [How do you change the color of the dotted line on Google map v3 directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35502342/how-do-you-change-the-color-of-the-dotted-line-on-google-map-v3-directions)

You can not use the directions renderer at all and render the directions yourself (leave the panel if you want it)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/hxj4j8bs/26/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var directions = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var renderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
  suppressPolylines: true,
  suppressMarkers: true
});
var map, transitLayer;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7482333, -73.8681295),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
  google.maps.event.addListener(renderer, "routeindex_changed", function() {

    renderDirectionsPolylines(renderer.getDirections(), renderer.getRouteIndex());
  });

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('go'), 'click', route);

  var input = document.getElementById('from');
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
  transitLayer = new google.maps.TransitLayer();
  var control = document.getElementById('transit-wpr');
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(control);

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(control, 'click', function() {
    transitLayer.setMap(transitLayer.getMap() ? null : map);
  });
  addDepart();
  route();
}

function addDepart() {
  var depart = document.getElementById('depart');
  for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 60; j += 15) {
      var x = i < 10 ? '0' + i : i;
      var y = j < 10 ? '0' + j : j;
      depart.innerHTML += '<option>' + x + ':' + y + '</option>';
    }
  }
}

function route() {
  var departure = document.getElementById('depart').value;
  var bits = departure.split(':');
  var now = new Date();
  var tzOffset = (now.getTimezoneOffset() + 60) * 60 * 1000;
  var time = new Date();
  time.setHours(bits[0]);
  time.setMinutes(bits[1]);
  var ms = time.getTime() - tzOffset;
  if (ms < now.getTime()) {
    ms += 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  }
  var departureTime = new Date(ms);
  var request = {
    origin: document.getElementById('from').value,
    destination: '51 St, New York, NY 10022, USA',
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT,
    provideRouteAlternatives: true,
    transitOptions: {
      departureTime: departureTime
    }
  };
  var panel = document.getElementById('panel');
  panel.innerHTML = '';
  directions.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      renderer.setDirections(response);
      renderer.setMap(null);
      renderer.setPanel(panel);
      renderDirectionsPolylines(response);
      console.log(renderer.getDirections());
    } else {
      renderer.setMap(null);
      renderer.setPanel(null);
    }
  });
}
var polylineOptions = {
  strokeColor: '#C83939',
  strokeOpacity: 1,
  strokeWeight: 4
};
var walkingPolylineOptions = {
  strokeColor: '#C83939',
  strokeOpacity: 0,
  strokeWeight: 4,
  icons: [{
    icon: {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      fillColor: '#C83939',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      scale: 2,
      strokeColor: '#C83939',
      strokeOpacity: 1,
    },
    offset: '0',
    repeat: '10px'
  }]
};
var polylines = [];

function renderDirectionsPolylines(response, index) {
  if (!index) index = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < polylines.length; i++) {
    polylines[i].setMap(null);
  }
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var legs = response.routes[index].legs;
  for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
    var steps = legs[i].steps;
    for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
      var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
      var stepPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline(polylineOptions);
      if (steps[j].travel_mode == google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING) {
        stepPolyline.setOptions(walkingPolylineOptions)
      }
      for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
        stepPolyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
        bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
      }
      stepPolyline.setMap(map);
      polylines.push(stepPolyline);
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: black;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}
#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
}
#panel-wpr {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
#panel {
  font-family: arial;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
#info {
  padding: 5px;
}
#from {
  width: 90%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.adp-directions {
  width: 100%;
}
.input {
  background-color: white;
  padding-left: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
  border-top: 1px solid silver;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;
}
.time {
  margin: 0;
  height: 17px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-top-color: #CCC;
  border-right-color: #999;
  border-left-color: #999;
  border-bottom-color: #CCC;
  padding: 2px 15px 1px 1px;
}
button {
  border: 1px solid #3079ED;
  color: white;
  background-color: #4D90FE;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#4D90FE), to(#4787ED));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE, #4787ED);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE, #4787ED);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE, #4787ED);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE, #4787ED);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #4D90FE, #4787ED);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#4d90fe', EndColorStr='#4787ed');
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 54px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 8px;
  line-height: 27px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.218s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.218s;
  -o-transition: all 0.218s;
  transition: all 0.218s;
}
#info div {
  line-height: 22px;
  font-size: 110%;
}
.btn {} #panel-wpr {
  border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}
#info {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.22&libraries=places"></script>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Transit</title>
<div id="transit-wpr">
  <button id="transit">Toggle transit layer</button>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="panel-wpr">
  <div id="info">
    <div>
      <h2>Transit directions</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>from:</label>
      <input class="input" id="from" value="Grand Central 42, NY">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>to:</label>
      <strong>51 St, New York, NY 10022, USA</strong>
    </div>
    <div>Depart at
      <select id="depart"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
      <button id="go">Get Directions</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="panel"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where I just needed to get rid of the "5R" label of the image in question. I had multiple routes on the map all with these [TransitLine](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions#TransitLine) markers and needed to remove them.

This worked as of google maps API version 3.40.9

```
var directionsRender;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initMap() {
  // setup map
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('address-map'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.507927, -0.0877726),
    zoom: 12
  });
}

directionsService.route(route_api_request, function(response, status) {
  if (status === 'OK') {
    // add in new response
    directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
    directionsRenderers.setMap(map);
  } else {
    window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
  }
});

function removeTransitLines() {
  if (directionsRenderer.getDirections().request.travelMode == 'TRANSIT') {
    var transit_steps_length = directionsRenderer.getDirections().routes[0].legs[0].steps.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < transit_steps_length - 1; i++) {
      try {
        // set the transitline to null
        directionsRenderer.getDirections().routes[0].legs[0].steps[i].transit = null;
      } catch (err) {
        // no transitline in this step so error is thrown
        continue;
      }
    }
    directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
  }
}
```

Basically you need to run through all the steps in the legs, in the route of the `directionsRenderer` object then set the ones that do have a transitLine to be null.