# Google Map API V3 how to draw walking path like GoogleMaps web applications?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my application I draw driving route from origin to destination using code like this:

```
directionsStartService.route(start_request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response); etc...
```

I added a new features to show intersectionPoints to path that user can do by walking, but I need to draw this paths like this:

https://www.google.it/maps/dir/Via+Giuseppe+Moruzzi,+1,+I-56124+Pisa+PI,+Italia/Dipartimento+di+Chimica+e+Chimica+Industriale/@43.7185239,10.4238179,18z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x12d591c15cbd6abd:0xb773ccba3d93b1d8!2m2!1d10.4222234!2d43.7185511!1m5!1m1!1s0x0:0xe33d73daefe47799!2m2!1d10.427329!2d43.7172621!3e2

Is it possible? I used Maps Javascript API.

Best regards,
Gianluca

Comment: related question: [How do you change the color of the dotted line on Google map v3 directions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35502342/how-do-you-change-the-color-of-the-dotted-line-on-google-map-v3-directions)

Comment: I would the dotted line because my path must be do by walking... I don't understand why I must select "transit".

Comment: Why would you have to select "transit" if you want walking directions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option, leveraging the code from the related question: [How do you change the color of the dotted line on Google map v3 directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35502342/how-do-you-change-the-color-of-the-dotted-line-on-google-map-v3-directions) (changing the travelMode to WALKING and adding an extra polyline from the end of the directions result to the location requested would be the code below.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/gceaa4L3/91/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var m1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    title: "start",
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.718526, 10.422241)
  });
  var m2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    title: "end",
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(43.717234, 10.427337)
  });

  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  calculateAndDisplayRoute(new google.maps.LatLng(43.718526, 10.422241),
    new google.maps.LatLng(43.717234, 10.427337),
    directionsService, directionsDisplay);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('right-panel'));
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(start, end, directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
  directionsService.route({
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      // directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      console.log(end.toUrlValue(6));
      renderDirectionsPolylines(response, start, end);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
var polylineOptions = {
  strokeColor: '#C83939',
  strokeOpacity: 1,
  strokeWeight: 4
};
var walkingPolylineOptions = {
  strokeColor: '#C83939',
  strokeOpacity: 0,
  strokeWeight: 4,
  icons: [{
    icon: {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      fillColor: '#C83939',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      scale: 2,
      strokeColor: '#C83939',
      strokeOpacity: 1,
    },
    offset: '0',
    repeat: '10px'
  }]
};
var walkingPolylineOptions2 = {
  strokeColor: '#C83939',
  strokeOpacity: 0,
  strokeWeight: 4,
  icons: [{
    icon: {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      fillColor: '#808080',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      scale: 2,
      strokeColor: '#808080',
      strokeOpacity: 1,
    },
    offset: '0',
    repeat: '10px'
  }]
};

function renderDirectionsPolylines(response, start, end) {
  var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
    var steps = legs[i].steps;
    for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
      var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
      var stepPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline(polylineOptions);
      if (steps[j].travel_mode == google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING) {
        stepPolyline.setOptions(walkingPolylineOptions)
      }
      for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
        stepPolyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
        bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
      }
      stepPolyline.setMap(map);
    }
  }
  if (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(start, stepPolyline.getPath().getAt(0)) > 1) {
    // add "dotted line"
    var extraLine1 = new google.maps.Polyline(walkingPolylineOptions2);
    extraLine1.setPath([stepPolyline.getPath().getAt(stepPolyline.getPath().getLength() - 1), end]);
    extraLine1.setMap(map);
  }
  if (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(end, stepPolyline.getPath().getAt(stepPolyline.getPath().getLength() - 1)) > 1) {
    // add "dotted line"
    var extraLine2 = new google.maps.Polyline(walkingPolylineOptions2);
    extraLine2.setPath([stepPolyline.getPath().getAt(stepPolyline.getPath().getLength() - 1), end]);
    extraLine2.setMap(map);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```