# Google Maps JavaScript API Display Two Routes with Different Polyline Styles on same Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, routes, driving-directions, map-directions

I am using the Google Maps JavaScript API and would like to display two routes (each with different polyline styles) on the same map.

The first route is by mode of driving and the start and finish locations are  an address input by the user and a parking garage chosen by the user respectively. This route will be displayed as a solid line.

The second route is by mode of walking. This route is from the parking garage to another static location on the same map defined as centerOfMap. This route will be displayed as dashed line with circle symbols.

Desired Output:

[image]

```
// Set the driving route line

var drivingPathLine = new google.maps.Polyline({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0,
    fillOpacity: 0
});

// Set the walking route line

var walkingLineSymbol = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    fillOpacity: 1,
    scale: 3
};

var walkingPathLine = new google.maps.Polyline({
    strokeColor: '#0eb7f6',
    strokeOpacity: 0,
    fillOpacity: 0,
    icons: [{
        icon: walkingLineSymbol,
        offset: '0',
        repeat: '10px'
    }],
});

directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({suppressMarkers:true,polylineOptions: walkingPathLine});
directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
```

The problem is, the way the code is currently written, only the second route (walking route) is displayed on the map. I know I need to place the polyline variables and directionsRenderer inside the getDirectionsHere method, but not sure how. Any guidance is appreciated!

How can I display the two routes on the same map and style each route different (one with a solid polyline and another with a dotted polyline)?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
    
html { 
 height: 100%;
}

body { 
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 26px;
    font-family: "filson-soft";
}

#map_container {
    height: 700px;
}

#map {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 float: left;
}
    
</style>

<div id="map_container">

    <div id="map"></div>
    
</div>
      
<script>
        
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);

        var centerOfMap;
        var geocoder;
        var map;
        var locations;
        var gmarkers = [];
        var search_lat;
        var search_lng;
        var infowindow;
        var directionsDisplay; 
        var directionsService;

        function initMap() {
            
            gmarkers = [];
            
            // Set the driving route line

            var drivingPathLine = new google.maps.Polyline({
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 0,
                fillOpacity: 0
            });

            // Set the walking route line

            var walkingLineSymbol = {
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                fillOpacity: 1,
                scale: 3
            };

            var walkingPathLine = new google.maps.Polyline({
                strokeColor: '#0eb7f6',
                strokeOpacity: 0,
                fillOpacity: 0,
                icons: [{
                    icon: walkingLineSymbol,
                    offset: '0',
                    repeat: '10px'
                }],
            });
            
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({suppressMarkers:true,polylineOptions: walkingPathLine});
            directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
            
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            
            // SET THE CENTER OF THE MAP
            
            centerOfMap = {
                lat: 38.5803844, 
                lng: -121.50024189999999
            };
            
            // ADD THE MAP AND SET THE MAP OPTIONS

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom: 16,
              center: centerOfMap
            });

            var center_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: centerOfMap,
                icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/orange-dot.png',
                map: map
            });
                  
            center_marker.addListener('click', function() {
                
                var gOneContent =   '<div id="info_window">' +
                                    '<h2>Center Of Map</h2>' +
                                    '<div style="clear:both;height:40px;">' +
                                    '<a href="#" id="getDirectionsButton" onclick="getDirectionsHere(' + centerOfMap.lat + ', ' + centerOfMap.lng + ');">Get Directions</a>' +
                                    '</div>';
                
                infowindow.setContent(gOneContent);
                infowindow.open(map, center_marker);
                map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
                
            });

            locations = [
                ["Joes Parking Garage","1001 6th St","Sacramento","CA","95814","38.58205649","-121.49857521","parking_garage"],
                ["Mikes Parking Garage","918 5th St","Sacramento","CA","95814","38.5826939","-121.50012016","parking_garage"]
            ];

            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            var marker, i;
            
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            
            console.log("found " + locations.length + " locations<br>");
            
            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

                var icon_image = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/parkinglot.png';
                
                var coordStr = locations[i][5] + "," + locations[i][6];
             var coords = coordStr.split(",");
             var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[0]),parseFloat(coords[1]));
                bounds.extend(pt);
                
                var location_name = locations[i][0];
                var location_address = locations[i][1] + ', ' + locations[i][2] + ', ' + locations[i][3] + ' ' + locations[i][4];

                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: pt,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    icon: icon_image,
                    map: map,
                    title: location_name,
                    address: location_address
                });
                
                gmarkers.push(marker);

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                    return function () {

                        var content = '<div id="info_window">'
                                      + '<h2 style="margin:0;">' + locations[i][0] + '</h2>'
                                      + locations[i][1] + ', ' + locations[i][2] + ', ' + locations[i][3] + ' ' + locations[i][4]
                                      + '<div style="clear:both;height:40px;">'
                                      + '<a href="#" id="getDirectionsButton" onclick="getDirectionsHere(' + locations[i][5] + ', ' + locations[i][6] + ');">Get Directions</a>';
                        
                        content += '</div>';
                        
                        content += '</div>';

                        infowindow.setContent(content);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());

                    }
                })(marker, i));
            }
        
        }
        
        function getDirectionsHere(lat,lng) {

            // GET THE SEARCH ADDRESS

            var address = 'Carmichael, CA';
            console.log('search address: ' + address);

            if (address) {

                geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        search_lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                        search_lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                        console.log('search FROM lat: ' + search_lat + ' search FROM lng: ' + search_lng);
                        console.log('search TO lat: ' + lat + ' search TO lng: ' + lng);
                        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
                    } else {
                        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                    }
                });

                // CHANGE THE ZOOM LEVEL AFTER THE USER SEARCHES TO FIT THE ROUTE WITHOUT SCROLLING

                map.setOptions({ minZoom: 10, maxZoom: 17 });
                map.setZoom(10);

                // INITIALIZE GOOGLE MAPS DIRECTIONS SERVICE 

                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions'));

                calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);

                // CALCULATE THE FIRST ROUTE AND DIRECTIONS (DRIVING) BASED ON ADDRESS

                function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
                    console.log('search address coordinates: ' + search_lat + ', ' + search_lng);
                    var selectedMode = document.getElementById('mode').value;
                    directionsService.route({
                      origin: {lat: search_lat, lng: search_lng},
                      destination: {lat: lat, lng: lng},
                      travelMode: "DRIVING"
                    }, function(response, status) {
                      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                      } else {
                        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
                      }
                    });
                }
                
                // CALCULATE THE SECOND ROUTE AND DIRECTIONS (WALKING) BETWEEN PARKINGG GARAGE AND FINAL DESTINATION "CENTER OF MAP"
                
                function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
                    var selectedMode = 'WALKING';
                    directionsService.route({
                      origin: {lat: lat, lng: lng},
                      destination: {lat: centerOfMap.lat, lng: centerOfMap.lng},
                      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode]
                    }, function(response, status) {
                      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                      } else {
                        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
                      }
                    });
                }

            } else {
                getLocationPopup();
                return;
            }

        }
        
    </script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry,places&callback=initMap"></script>

</body>
</html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you change the color of the dotted line on Google map v3 directions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35502342/how-do-you-change-the-color-of-the-dotted-line-on-google-map-v3-directions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues with your code:

1. the driving directions polyline is transparent (strokeOpacity: 0)
2. you have two `calculateAndDisplayRoute` functions, one for DRIVING, one for WALKING, that won't work in javascript, either give them two different names or make one function to handle the two cases:

```
    function calculateAndDisplayRoute(start, end, driving) {
      var selectedMode; 
      if (driving) selectedMode = "DRIVING";
      else selectedMode = "WALKING";
      directionsService.route({
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: selectedMode
      }, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          if (driving) {
            directionsDisplayD.setDirections(response);
            var start = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            var end = centerOfMap;
            calculateAndDisplayRoute(start, end, false);
          } else directionsDisplayW.setDirections(response);
        } else {
          window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/eze9cun8/1/)

[[image: screenshot driving + walking]

**code snippet:**

```js
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);

var centerOfMap;
var geocoder;
var map;
var locations;
var gmarkers = [];
var search_lat;
var search_lng;
var infowindow;
var directionsDisplayD;
var directionsDisplayW;
var directionsService;

function initMap() {

  gmarkers = [];

  // Set the driving route line

  var drivingPathLine = new google.maps.Polyline({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 1
  });

  // Set the walking route line

  var walkingLineSymbol = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    fillOpacity: 1,
    scale: 3
  };

  var walkingPathLine = new google.maps.Polyline({
    strokeColor: '#0eb7f6',
    strokeOpacity: 0,
    fillOpacity: 0,
    icons: [{
      icon: walkingLineSymbol,
      offset: '0',
      repeat: '10px'
    }],
  });

  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  // SET THE CENTER OF THE MAP

  centerOfMap = {
    lat: 38.5803844,
    lng: -121.50024189999999
  };

  // ADD THE MAP AND SET THE MAP OPTIONS

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 16,
    center: centerOfMap
  });

  directionsDisplayW = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    suppressMarkers: true,
    polylineOptions: walkingPathLine,
    map: map,
    preserveViewport: true
  });
  directionsDisplayD = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    suppressMarkers: true,
    polylineOptions: drivingPathLine,
    map: map
  });

  var center_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: centerOfMap,
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/orange-dot.png',
    map: map
  });

  center_marker.addListener('click', function() {

    var gOneContent = '<div id="info_window">' +
      '<h2>Center Of Map</h2>' +
      '<div style="clear:both;height:40px;">' +
      '<a href="#" id="getDirectionsButton" onclick="getDirectionsHere(' + centerOfMap.lat + ', ' + centerOfMap.lng + ');">Get Directions</a>' +
      '</div>';

    infowindow.setContent(gOneContent);
    infowindow.open(map, center_marker);
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());

  });

  locations = [
    ["Joes Parking Garage", "1001 6th St", "Sacramento", "CA", "95814", "38.58205649", "-121.49857521", "parking_garage"],
    ["Mikes Parking Garage", "918 5th St", "Sacramento", "CA", "95814", "38.5826939", "-121.50012016", "parking_garage"]
  ];

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  console.log("found " + locations.length + " locations<br>");

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

    var icon_image = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/parkinglot.png';

    var coordStr = locations[i][5] + "," + locations[i][6];
    var coords = coordStr.split(",");
    var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[0]), parseFloat(coords[1]));
    bounds.extend(pt);

    var location_name = locations[i][0];
    var location_address = locations[i][1] + ', ' + locations[i][2] + ', ' + locations[i][3] + ' ' + locations[i][4];

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pt,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      icon: icon_image,
      map: map,
      title: location_name,
      address: location_address
    });

    gmarkers.push(marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {

        var content = '<div id="info_window">' + '<h2 style="margin:0;">' + locations[i][0] + '</h2>' + locations[i][1] + ', ' + locations[i][2] + ', ' + locations[i][3] + ' ' + locations[i][4] + '<div style="clear:both;height:40px;">' + '<a href="#" id="getDirectionsButton" onclick="getDirectionsHere(' + locations[i][5] + ', ' + locations[i][6] + ');">Get Directions</a>';

        content += '</div>';

        content += '</div>';

        infowindow.setContent(content);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());

      }
    })(marker, i));
  }
}

function getDirectionsHere(lat, lng) {

  // GET THE SEARCH ADDRESS

  var address = 'Carmichael, CA';
  console.log('search address: ' + address);

  if (address) {

    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        search_lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        search_lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        console.log('search FROM lat: ' + search_lat + ' search FROM lng: ' + search_lng);
        console.log('search TO lat: ' + lat + ' search TO lng: ' + lng);
        var start = new google.maps.LatLng(search_lat, search_lng);
        var end = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(start, end, true);
        // CHANGE THE ZOOM LEVEL AFTER THE USER SEARCHES TO FIT THE ROUTE WITHOUT SCROLLING

        map.setOptions({
          minZoom: 10,
          maxZoom: 17
        });
        map.setZoom(10);

        // INITIALIZE GOOGLE MAPS DIRECTIONS SERVICE 

        // directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplayD.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions'));
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });


    // CALCULATE THE FIRST ROUTE AND DIRECTIONS (DRIVING) BASED ON ADDRESS

    function calculateAndDisplayRoute(start, end, driving) {
      console.log('start address coordinates: ' + start.lat() + ', ' + start.lng());
      var selectedMode; // = document.getElementById('mode').value;
      if (driving) selectedMode = "DRIVING";
      else selectedMode = "WALKING";
      directionsService.route({
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: selectedMode
      }, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          if (driving) {
            directionsDisplayD.setDirections(response);

            var start = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            var end = centerOfMap;
            calculateAndDisplayRoute(start, end, false);

          } else directionsDisplayW.setDirections(response);
        } else {
          window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: "filson-soft";
}
#map_container {
  height: 100%;
}
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places"></script>
<div id="map_container">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```